# Admin page cannot show custom model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I created a two custom models: `Picture` and `Album`

I have migrated them into the database and both tables exist in the database

In admin, I want to create a custom management panel, so in the **admin.py** I have

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from testrest.models import Picture, Album

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['album_name']
admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
```

*My **models.py** file:*

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_name

class Picture(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    google_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateField()
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_added',)
```

*The error I get:*

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/testrest/album/
relation "testrest_album" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "testrest_album"
                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:5000/admin/testrest/album/
Django Version: 1.7.7
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "testrest_album" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "testrest_album"
                             ^
Exception Location: /home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 65
Python Executable:  /home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/yonk/projects/apple',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/bin',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 26 Mar 2015 22:24:13 +0000
```

Comment: Can you access your models from the Django shell? `django-admin.py shell`

Comment: Yes I can. Picture has a 'ManyToManyField' linked to Album, could that cause problems with Admin page?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you remove the `fields` and just add `pass`?

Comment: I still get the same error. Let me also post my models.py

Comment: I've used your code on a fresh virtual env with Django 1.7.7 and it works. Could you be using a different database when accessing the admin site? Have you run a `migrate` in that environment?

Comment: Thanks andrew. I am also suspecting its connected to a different db. I created a dummy user in Admin page, but its not showing up on my auth_user table. I have double checked my settings.py and migrate, everything seems to be pointed to the correct db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
It was somehow connected to a different database, there was a ghost session of Gunicorn running in the background, after killing the process and restart Gunicorn the problem is fixed